# python "self" parameter while calling function from another file

Tags: python, file, call

Sorry, Im new to Python and have a basic q

I have 2 python files

FileA.py

```
Class ABC:
        def __init__(self, loggingLevel = 20):
            self.data = None
            logging.basicConfig(level=loggingLevel)
            pass


        def asd(self, text)
            *
            *
if __name__ == '__main__':
        X=ABC(10)
        Y=X.asd(text)
```

I have another file FileB.py from where i want to call function asd. I have the parameter 'text' to pass, but what should i pass for parameter 'self'. tried many options , but when it goes to File A, its failing as the value of self is not correct

Comment: Create an instance of the class ABC and call the function using "instance.functionname(<params>)" here the instance itself will be passed as self. No need to explicitly pass the self as Param.

Comment: the answer is nothing. the self is internal for that class

Comment: Self is self referencing object, before deep diving into python I would reckon to read this, can explain you what exactly self does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self

Answer (score 0):

`self` is implicitly passed if you have a reference to an instance of the containing class. In other words, you can do the same thing that you did in `main` in the `FileB.py`:

**`FileB.py`**

```
from FileA import ABC

X = ABC(10)
Y = X.asd(text)
```

Comment: Thanks Sumner, its going into function asd, but after that there is s line in asd which says self.data[column] = self.data[column].str.replace(r'[\n\r\t]+', ' ')  , where it is throwing error " TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: The code you show sets `self.data` to `None` - you need to set it to some sort of subscriptable value for the line to show above to work.

Comment: Also when FileA is run, its working fine.   I set self.Data=[] in File A. When im calling from File B, its staying index should be integer and not str.